# Настроить фон для элемента WPF ListViewItem. Задать стиль/шаблон

Tags: wpf, wpf-шаблоны, wpf-стили

Делаю первое приложение на WPF .Net Framework, возникла необходимость создать ListView для вывода списка "клиентов". В C# получаю список, для клиентов создан класс, поэтому с выводом контента проблем не возникло.

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" BasedOn="{StaticResource HomePageListView}">
        <Setter Property="View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Username" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding username}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}"/>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Но есть одно "но". Встроенные стили для ListViewItem'ов просто вырвиглазные, поэтому я решил подправить фон.

[image: Верхний элемент "IsSelected", нижний "IsMouseOver"]

При попытке сменить цвет простым кодом:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="HomePageListViewItem">
     <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#475b63"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2e2c2f"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#475b63"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Получаю следующее.

[image: Верхний элемент "IsSelected", нижний "IsMouseOver"]

**Вопрос: как убрать это дурацкое разделение фона на 2 полоски и можно ли вообще?** Я попробовать создать Template, однако, это не дало никаких результатов, потому что простыми ContentPresentor'ами или TextBlock'ами это не поправишь, так как у них нету триггеров "IsSelected".

Comment: Эти 2 полоски - выделенный пункт и тот, над которым мышь. Убирать - только шаблон менять. И IsSelected есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам простой шаблон. Подсвечивает только текущий элемент. Попутно `HorizontalContentAlignment` лечит неработающее выравнивание в ячейках

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Работает  всё, кроме IsSelected.
UPD. Работает, когда добавил на саму страничку окошка с ListView. Однако, почему-то не работает из ResourceDictionary со стилями. Но я уже привык, что половина свойств оттуда не работают, приходится на месте клепать.

Comment: UPD2. Всё сработало внезапно и в ResourceDictionary, хотя по факту я ничего не менял.